# Can I bundle react.js apps into multiple modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, systemjs, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

Let's say I have a website with multiple tabs, built with react.js, and each tab contains a large amount of data. Normally webpack bundles react apps into a single bundle, but this would be a waste of resources if you never visit one of the tabs. Is it possible to break it into separate bundles without having to re-bundle react core & react DOM, and then call these extra static modules upon request?

I'm open to different suggestions - webpack, systemjs etc.

Comment: are those amount of data fetched from an API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check your architecture and make sure you **actually** need this. Considering the typical scenario in which only the "infrastructure" is part of the bundle and **all data** is downloaded via Ajax as they are needed, it is kind of unlikely (not impossible) that you will end up with a particularly large bundle when you [properly take care of optimization](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app).

Back to your question...

Bear in mind that this might not be a walk in the park. From my experience, when you're trying to do something a little off the dotted line, problems start to pop up down the road. You might have problems with server-rendering, redux or whatever.

Anyway, you got 2 options:

### 1) Using a multi-page app configuration

Webpack will output multiple "chunks" with you configure it to have multiple entry points like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        p1: "./page1",
        p2: "./page2",
        p3: "./page3"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].entry.chunk.js"
    }
}
```

You can even have "common chunks". [Take a look here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app).

### 2) Using code splitting

There's a Webpack loader called [bundle-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/bundle-loader) that offers a `lazy` option that allows modules to be actually downloaded as they are needed. I came across this loader when I was reading the `React-Router 4` documentation. They even provide an example which doesn't require the router at all, [check it here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting).

Comment: Ah, I was just looking at that react training guide earlier... if only I had scrolled down a little further to code splitting :D
Thanks, great answer